# Identifying most important words in text classification

Tags: machine-learning, text-mining

I know one can use tf-idf to distinguish important words based on the number of times a word appears in a document relative to the number of times it appears in the entire collection of documents. However, how does one identify which words are most important in *distinguishing* the positive class from the negative class?

Comment: What you mean by _positive_ or _negative_ class?

Comment: For example, if you're performing sentiment analysis, so there are two classes (positive or negative).

Answer (score 2):

Create a simple [Naive Bayes classifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier) over a corpus of positive and negative sentiments , and weights words with probability of it is positive or not , for example word "fantastic" appears 80 times in positives and 20 times in negatives so it has probability of 0.8 for word "fantastic" that sentiment is positive , after assign weight to words , you can create a [bag of word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model) of a new sentiment, ignore non positive and negative words , calculate probability of that sentence for each positive and negative word as follows :

$$
p(negative|s) = p(negative)p(w_1,w_2,w_3,...,w_n)
$$
$$
p(positive|s) = p(positive)p(w_1,w_2,w_3,...,w_n)
$$

Which one is greater has more probability for $$ s=w_1,w_2,w_3,...,w_n $$

There are many good improvement that you can use here, bag of word ignores positions of words and dependency between them , you can don't ignore them , and you can use [discriminative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879432/what-is-the-difference-between-a-generative-and-discriminative-algorithm) models over generative models(like Naive Bayes) or use some other classifiers like [SVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine) or ... ,